# Minimal USB-SIE code example for PIC16F1454 and question about windows driver

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb

Im new to PIC microcontrollers. Im looking for minimal USB-SIE (Serial Interface Engine) code example for PIC16F1454.

I was browsing Microchip forum, but there are examples with so many details...

Questions:

**Where I can find send and receive byte example with schematic?**

**Do I need to install Windows driver for USB-SIE, or it will work natively?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: So where I should look for help? At stackoverflow, where 99% of users have no idea how PIC16F1454 looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the PIC16F1454 and PIC16F1459 is that the former has no analog components.  Even though the Microchip MLA for looks daunting, you don't need most of it.  If you want work from the Microchip MLA for say the Mouse Demo or custom HID you only need to do a few things.

- Select LPCUSBDK_16F1459 as your configuration.  This will tell the compiler to use the configuration files in */low_count_usb_development_kit/pic16f1459/.. .
- Select the chip as the 16F1454 under project properties.
- There are a few uses of the ADC, which will prevent you from compiling for the 1454.  You do not need them so you can use search to get rid of any use of them in the PIC16F1459 files.
- If you don't have an external oscillator you need to adjust the configuration settings in Source Files/app/system_config/.../pic16f1459/system.c to use the internal oscillator.  All you need to do is define USE_INTERNAL_OSC. Also, you need to put a line somewhere to set ACTCON = 0x90.  This allows active clock tuning with clock synchronization done via the SOF signal from the USB host.

*Disclaimer*: This is the quick and dirty way.  One should make their own configuration and copy paste the file contents of the other header files as needed.

As for the driver, you shouldn't need to any USB driver for standard devices like a USB mouse/keyboard.  For the custom HID and others the MLA contains source code for writing your own USB driver.  It is common to have to write (or at least compile) your own drivers natively.

Comment: But I don't want HID device. I want serial port... HID works on serial port?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? USB-SIE is the hardware portion of the PIC that takes care of certain USB tasks so you don't have to program them in.  In the USB protocol it is no easier to send one byte than to send multiple bytes (a packet).

Comment: I mean "Serial Interface Engine". I thought It works like RS-232 (or CDC?). I hate usb... 1353253 lines of code to send 1 byte of data :(

Comment: The serial interface engine is a piece of hardware inside the PIC.  Do you want to know about USB to RS-232?

Answer (score 2):

I think CDC (communications device class) is the acronym you mean, rather than SIE. USB-CDC is a standard way of emulating a serial port over USB.

See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176939/do-i-need-to-write-my-own-host-side-usb-driver-for-a-cdc-device) and [this page from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538820%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for what is required in the way of windows drivers - essentially just an .ini file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about this, buy Jan Axelson's [Complete USB.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931448086)  If you just want usb for your project, use a FTDI chip. Or, get one of the microchip USB demo kits.

Any particular reason for choosing the 16 series? I would say the pic18/24/32 will have better support and help.

What windows sees is entirely based on your supporting code.

Comment: Reason is... cost. With PIC16F1454 I can replace microcontroller and FTDI chip in my project. I can significantly reduce cost of my simple device.

Comment: Warning..  Don't plan on reliability with the windows cdc driver, it has had/has? some known long term reliability issues.

Comment: I know, I had these issues with first FT232 chips few years ago, before better drivers were released by FTDI. How about Microchip CDC? I saw them somewhere. Are they fully reliable?

Comment: I don't think microchip has their own cdc driver, they use the windows drivers in their demos.

Comment: So... Without writing drivers I can make reliable HID device and thats all?

Comment: I don't know, just saying check it out.  I have had good luck with HID though, but remember you won't get the throughput of cdc.